# Maximum width of a like button in any language (internationalization)?

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-like

I am working on a site that will have very high international distribution and need to understand the maximum width of a like button in any of the available languages.

So far, the biggest Like button I can find is in Russian - http://cl.ly/Jmeb. 
Is there a full specification list containing the size of the like button for each available language?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most robust way to design your site is to not impose tight limits on the size of the Like button. The [Facebook Developers topic *Internationalization*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/) says,

> **Avoid Layouts Relying on Precise Sizing**
>
> Try not to use layouts that depend on the precise onscreen sizes of pieces of text in the original language. For any piece of text, in some languages it is likely to be shorter and in some it will be longer (sometimes significantly so in either direction.) If you have sized your user interface elements such that your text just barely fits, your application will probably not work well in a language with longer words.

Similarly, the [Facebook Developers topic *Like Button*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) says,

> You may need to adjust the width of the Like button to accommodate different languages.

You found a Like button in Russian that is 110 pixels wide. Can your layout work with a button that is 1.5 times as wide? 2 times as wide? 5 times as wide?  Then you are probably safe.

But the browser is retrieving they Like button image from Facebook when it displays your page, right?  So even if we can give you a full list of the size of the Like button for each available language *today*, tomorrow Facebook could add another language which has a longer Like button.

That said, Facebook does give code for [getting the Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) in any language you choose (see FAQ: How do I display the Like button in different languages?):
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=fr_FR&...

Facebook also publishes an XML file listing [the locales that Facebook supports](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml). With a bit of Grep search/replace, we can generate an HTML page which displays Like buttons in all 76 locales listed today.  Looking at the width of those buttons, we see that Irish localisation of the Like button is the widest at the moment, with 127 pixels. (On my system, the Like button in Malayalam comes up a bit wider at 169 pixels, but that's because I don't have a Malayalam font installed, so the button displays with missing-glyph boxes.)

So, it looks like the maximum width of a Like button in the languages supported at the moment 169 pixels wide. But, coding to this width is not what Facebook, or good internationalisation design, recommends. Instead, make your layout flexible, and able to cope with wider Like buttons in some locales.